# It's not clear (to me) how the 'promoter' and 'benefactor' badges differ

Tags: support

**Benefactor** - First bounty you manually award on your own question.
**Promoter** - First bounty you offer on your own question.

Don't you award a bounty on a question within a week after offering a bounty on that question?

Comment: Basically, you get the "Promoter" badge for _starting_ a bounty- You get the "Benefactor" badge when you _manually_ select an answer to award the bounty to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kendra explained it well enough in the comments above, but I think that you might be confused about how these two badges wouldn't both happen.

When you start a bounty on your own question, you get the "Promoter" badge. That is pretty self explanatory. The reason you may not always get the "Benefactor" badge with the "Promoter" badge is because bounties are not always manually awarded. You can find a good explanation of automatic bounty awarding [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/284141).

> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty (provided that the answer was posted during the bounty period). Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Comment: Hmm, sounds a bit redundant. Oh well.

Comment: @einpoklum It's intended to encourage investment in the question you're asking. Some people (particularly those new to SE - bronze badges mostly teach you about the site) put bounties on questions, then just wait for the answers to roll in and for some reason just don't come back to award it or accept an answer.

Comment: @Emrakul: I don't know about you, but when I had < 500 reputation, I wouldn't pay 50 of it for all the bronze badges in the world.

Comment: @einpoklum It's not about the badges. Suppose you want attention on your question, so you set a bounty. Then, _afterward_, you either end up    assigning or not assigning the bounty. The second badge is there to encourage you to reward the bounty _once it's been set_; the first is there to let you know that setting a bounty is an option in the first place.

Comment: @Emrakul: Even if we forget about the badges - reputation-poor people can't afford bounties. They're just too expensive. Unless it's some kind of life-or-death situation.